# Who wins in Uno: Disney Parks Edition when someone wins with the Magic card?

Tags: uno

The Disney Parks edition of Uno has a special wild card called the "Wild Disney Parks Magic Card" which has the following explanatory text:

> When you play this card, all players must pass their ENTIRE hand to the player on their left. This card is also a wild card, so you choose the color that resumes play. If this card is turned up at the beginning of play, the person to the left of the dealer chooses the color that begins play.

If someone goes out by playing this card, we have a dilemma. Which is right?

1. The hands are rotated, thus causing the player to the left of the person who played the card to win the round
2. Play stops immediately, thus causing the person who played it to win the round

Comment: I don't have an official answer, but I think it's going to produce more interesting play patterns if the person playing the card _loses_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [unorules.com](https://www.unorules.com/):

> #### What if your last card is a Wild Swap Hands or a Wild Shuffle Hands?
>
> This scenario may happen from time to time. If your last card is a Wild Swap Hands or Wild Shuffle Hands card, you can treat it like a normal Wild card and play it to end the game right there and then – No further action is required. This is because you would obviously not win the game if you were required to swap your hand with another player (in the case of a Wild Swap Hands card) or to receive new cards from other players (in the case of a Wild Shuffle Hands card).

I'm not sure how reputable this site is, and also it doesn't seem to be referring to the Disney Parks edition, but it is very similar.

To respond to Philip Kendall's comment, that was my first thought as well, however upon further inspection, I think it is actually less interesting that way, as you pretty much have no choice but the play the card right away if you get it, as you can never win as long as you have it. Also, this version of Uno had slightly different scoring, where you collect your opponents points if you win, as opposed to the golf-scoring method, so that meant there can't be a strategy to causing the player to your left to win when you thought you might have few points in the hand to your right. There may be rare situations where it is to your advantage to keep it, but I think they are extremely rare.

Comment: "as you pretty much have no choice but the play the card right away if you get it, as you can never win as long as you have it." Absolutely definitely not. Once you get the card, you take the option to draw cards when you can (you don't have to play a card, even if you can) and wait until your RHS opponent has a small hand. Then strike, getting a small hand while passing on a large one. Of course, other players may suspect you are doing this and start drawing cards themselves... or were you bluffing?

Comment: @PhilipKendall that is exactly the strategy i employed, before we realized the different scoring rules